# How do I put a timer that counts up in HTML5 Canvas with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've made the beginning of a platformer game with a sprite-character. I want to be able to be able to have a timer somewhere in the top-left corner that counts up for every second (00:00, 00:01).

I've kinda done a timer before, but that was counted down and this is different because I'm using requestAnimationframe for my game loop. Would be grateful for some tips on how to accomplish this.

I've made a death counter already using this code:

```
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillText("Deaths: " + deaths, 50, 50);
```

with deaths++ in a function that resets the position of the player. However, I can't figure out how to proceed.

Here is a jsFiddle of my game (you might have to zoom out, game is 1300x600. Arrowkeys to control character.):

https://jsfiddle.net/z3orewvb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly said you can do the timer in your `loop()`, so it is more coupled to the game logic and rendering. Just store the starting time outside, and whenever you redraw, calculate the difference:

```js
let start=Date.now();
function reset() {
  start=Date.now();
}
let x=0,y=0,dx=0,dy=0;
function loop() {
  let seconds=Math.floor((Date.now()-start)/1000);
  let minutes=Math.floor(seconds/60);
  seconds%=60;
  dx+=x<cnv.width/2?1:-1;
  dy+=y<cnv.height/2?1:-1;
  x+=dx;
  y+=dy;
  let ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle="#8080FF";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,30,15);
  ctx.strokeText(minutes.toString().padStart(2,"0")+":"+seconds.toString().padStart(2,"0"),0,10);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();
```

```html
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button><br>
<canvas id="cnv"></canvas>
```

Of course there is a generic repeating timer, [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). But then you may have artifacts if there is anything else drawn on the same location:

```js
let x=0,y=0,dx=0,dy=0;
function loop() {
  dx+=x<cnv.width/2?1:-1;
  dy+=y<cnv.height/2?1:-1;
  x+=dx;
  y+=dy;
  let ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle="#8080FF";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();

let start=Date.now();
let counter=0;
function reset() {
  start=Date.now();
  counter=0;
}
setInterval(()=>{
  let ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,30,25);
  let seconds=Math.floor((Date.now()-start)/1000);
  let minutes=Math.floor(seconds/60);
  seconds%=60;
  ctx.strokeText(minutes.toString().padStart(2,"0")+":"+seconds.toString().padStart(2,"0"),0,10);
  counter++;
  minutes=Math.floor(counter/60);
  seconds=counter%60;
  ctx.strokeText(minutes.toString().padStart(2,"0")+":"+seconds.toString().padStart(2,"0"),0,20);
},1000);
function problem() {
  let wait=Date.now()+1500;
  while(Date.now()<wait);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button><button onclick="problem()">Problem</button><br>
<canvas id="cnv"></canvas>
```

Also, a "Problem" button has been added (press it a couple times): `setInterval()` does its best, but it is not bulletproof, it does not compensate for missed/skipped schedules, that second simply has not happened for the `setInterval()`-based counter (the lower one).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this.. In the callback function, I pass back the `interval` object, so that if needed, you can clear the interval so it doesn't continue to run in the background.. (or if you need to stop the counter at a certain point).. In this demo, I stop the counter at 11..

```js
function counter(callback) {
  var i = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(function() {
    callback(i, interval);
    i++;
  }, 1000);
}

counter((currentTime, intervalObject) => {
  if (currentTime === 11) {
    clearInterval(intervalObject);
  } else {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const data = `
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>
<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>
<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>
<pre>${currentTime}</pre>
</div>
</foreignObject>
</svg>
`;
    const img = new Image();
    const svg = new Blob([data], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```